# kubectl deployment failure error: standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: no such file or directory

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, deployment

Base docker file

```
FROM docker.repo.abs.com/alpine
ENV MULE_HOME /opt/mule
ENV MULE_VERSION 4.4.0

# Setup a non-root user
 

# application port


COPY mule-enterprise-standalone-${MULE_VERSION} support-collector support-watcher ${MULE_HOME}/
COPY arm.sh ${MULE_HOME}/bin/
COPY jq /usr/bin/

RUN apk update && \
    apk add openjdk8  && \
    wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.32-r0/glibc-2.32-r0.apk && \
    apk  add --force-overwrite glibc-2.32-r0.apk && \
    apk add --update curl && \
    apk add bash && \
    apk add sudo && \
    rm *.apk && \
    apk upgrade && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/** && \
    rm "/etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub" && \
    chmod +x /usr/bin/jq && \
    chown -R muser:muser /opt && \
    chmod -R 777 /opt && \
    echo '%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/wheel && \
    adduser muser wheel && \
    sudo -lU muser

WORKDIR /opt/mule/bin
USER muser
RUN sudo whoami
ENTRYPOINT [ "./arm.sh" ]
```

Getting this error while trying to deploy below docker file image on Kubernetes.
References https://github.com/giovtorres/slurm-docker-cluster/issues/19 and tried converting all files from CRLF to LF, but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Add this before ENTRYPOINT:

`RUN chmod +x arm.sh`

Also make sure that arm.sh has appropriate line endings (linux lf instead of windows crlf) on the machine you issue `docker build` command